# Strange behaviour with AngularJS pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I've been trying to implement this AngularJS table pagination http://jsfiddle.net/EnY74/20/ the problem is now I've inserted it into the site minus the css bootstrap the pagination is displaying 1,222 entries when there should only be around 12 entries. I am also quite the novice with javascript.

It's replicating entries 20 times or something then replicating the second entry 20 times and so on.

Take a look here jsfiddle.net/vsfsugkg/1 changed table entries of only row and they are repeated 1,222 times? i think the content is being pulled from somewhere else?

Here's the JS file contents.

```
'use strict';

var App = angular.module('PaginationApp', []);

App.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'TypekitService', '$filter', function($scope, Typekit, $filter){
$scope.loadData = function(){                         Typekit.getTypekits($scope.page, $scope.per_page).then(function(response){                    
        $scope.more = response.data.library.families.length === $scope.per_page;
        $scope.families = $scope.families.concat(response.data.library.families);
        $scope.status_bar = "Showing " + ($scope.families.length === 0 ? "0" : "1") + " to " + $filter('number')($scope.families.length) + " of " + $filter('number')(response.data.library.pagination.count) + " entries";

    });
};

$scope.show_more = function(){
    $scope.page += 1;
    $scope.loadData();
}

$scope.has_more = function(){
    return $scope.more;
}

$scope.per_page = 10;
$scope.page = 1;        
$scope.families = [];        
$scope.more = true;
$scope.status_bar = "";
$scope.loadData();    
}])


App.factory('TypekitService',['$http',function($http){
return {
    getTypekits : function(page, per_page){
        return $http.jsonp('https://typekit.com/api/v1/json/libraries/full?page='+page+'&per_page='+per_page+'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
    }
}
}]);
```

Comment: Hardcode the per page variable, does it still not work? 
`$scope.more = response.data.library.families.length === 10;`

Comment: I got the same result

Comment: Opps, sorry, I mean the URL when calling for items: `https://typekit.com/api/v1/json/libraries/full?page='+page+'&per_page=10&callback=JSON_CALLBACK` - It'll rule out an issue with the server.

Comment: that stopped the pagination from working

Comment: I don't get it - it works fine on jsfiddle

Comment: @AdrianLynch I think the table is trying to pull data from whatever the data was being pulled from on jsfiddle they have exactly the same amount of entries.

Comment: data library families

Comment: If the code on JSF is the same as what you're using, what else is going on? Got anything else that's running? Is it failing with a reduced codebase?

Comment: if you read the file contents above it is somehow pulling data library families to populate the table as it was in demo mode on jsfiddle I need to tell this file to stop pulling data libraries to populate the table but im a novice and need help

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vsfsugkg/1/ changed table entries of only row and they are repeated 1,222 times ??????